# How to apply KVL with current source?

Tags: current, current-source, passive-networks, kirchhoffs-laws

In order to write an ODE for the inductor current I have to write a KVL equation that includes the current source. How do I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For KCL,

$$
\begin{align*}
I_{_\text{L}}+I_{_\text{C}}&=I_1
\\\\
I_{_\text{L}}+C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}V_{_\text{C}}&=I_1
\\\\
I_{_\text{L}}+C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,I_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,I_{_\text{L}}\right)&=I_1
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}I_{_\text{L}}+\frac{R_2}{L_1}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}+\frac1{L_1\,C_1}I_{_\text{L}}&=\frac{I_1}{L_1\,C_1}
\end{align*}
$$

Two initial conditions at \$t=0\$ are needed: \$I_{_\text{L}}\$ and \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}\$. But \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}=\frac{V_{_\text{L}}}{L_1}\$ and \$V_{_\text{L}}=V_{_\text{C}}-R_2\,I_{_\text{L}}\$. With \$V_{_\text{C}}\$ and \$I_{_\text{L}}\$ known at \$t=0\$, all that's needed to move forward to a specific solution is present.

It's possible to also write the KCL as:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac1{L_1}\int V_{_\text{L}}\:\text{d}t+C_1\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{C}}&=I_1
\\\\
\frac1{L_1\,C_1}\int V_{_\text{L}}\:\text{d}t+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{C}}&=\frac{I_1}{C_1}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,V_{_\text{C}}+\frac1{L_1\,C_1} V_{_\text{L}}&=0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}^2}
\end{align*}
$$

But since \$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{C}}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,\frac{V_{_\text{L}}}{L_1}\$ it follows:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{L}}+R_2\cdot\frac{V_{_\text{L}}}{L_1}\right)+\frac1{L_1\,C_1} V_{_\text{L}}&=0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}^2}
\\\\
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,V_{_\text{L}}+\frac{R_2}{L_1}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,V_{_\text{L}}+\frac1{L_1\,C_1}\,V_{_\text{L}}&=0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}^2}
\end{align*}
$$

Different direction.

That can be moved back towards the original direction mentioned at the outset above by noting that \$V_{_\text{L}}=L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}\$ and substituting in:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}+\frac{R_2}{L_1}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}+\frac1{L_1\,C_1}\,L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}&=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\frac{I_1}{C_1}=0\:\frac{\text{V}}{\text{s}^2}
\\\\
L_1\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,I_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}+\frac1{C_1}\,I_{_\text{L}}&=\frac{I_1}{C_1}
\\\\
L_1\,C_1\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}t^2}\,I_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,C_1\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}+I_{_\text{L}}&=I_1
\\\\
C_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\left(L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\,I_{_\text{L}}+R_2\,I_{_\text{L}}\right)+I_{_\text{L}}&=I_1
\end{align*}
$$

And it's a short step from there to the original result at top.

Lots of ways to go.

The upshot is that \$I_1=I_{_\text{L}}+C_1\left(R_2\,\dot{I_{_\text{L}}}+L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\ddot{I_{_\text{L}}}\right)\$ since \$R_2\,\dot{I_{_\text{L}}}\$ is the rate of change of voltage across \$R_2\$ and \$L_1\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\ddot{I_{_\text{L}}}\$ is the rate of change of voltage across \$L_1\$. The sum of these two gives the rate of change of voltage across \$C_1\$.

Does any of this help you when considering KVL/mesh? The left loop is nothing more than the statement that the voltage across the current source, \$I_1\$, is the same as the voltage across the capacitor, \$C_1\$. And \$I_1\$ is obviously the same as the left side's loop current. So all that's really left to worry over is the KVL for the right loop. Treating the right loop current as equal to \$I_{_\text{L}}\$ and in the same direction, then this will be \$V_{_\text{C}}-\frac1{L_1}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}-R_2\,I_{_\text{L}}=0\:\text{V}\$.

\$V_{_\text{C}}=\frac1{C_1}\int I_{_\text{C}}\:\text{d}t=\frac1{C_1}\int \left(I_1-I_{_\text{L}}\right)\:\text{d}t\$ so \$\frac1{C_1}\int \left(I_1-I_{_\text{L}}\right)\:\text{d}t-\frac1{L_1}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}I_{_\text{L}}-R_2\,I_{_\text{L}}=0\:\text{V}\$.

This is quickly transformed to earlier results already shown.

Answer (score 0):

First, The equation in the box is incorrect.

Remember that \$i_C=C\frac{dv_C}{dt}\$.

Second, \$i_C\$ can be substituted from the KCL equation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in order to add a useful answer (despite the other answers, which are great) I'll show a method that used Laplace transform. First, we want to find the inductor current so we can use the current divider formula:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{I}_\text{L}\left(\text{s}\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{1}{\text{sC}}+\text{sL}+\text{R}}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\text{sC}}{\text{sC}}}{\displaystyle\frac{\text{sC}}{\text{sC}}+\text{sC}\text{sL}+\text{sC}\text{R}}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\cdot\text{I}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Using the convolution property of the Laplace transform we can write:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{i}_\text{L}\left(t\right)&=\int\limits_0^t\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\text{I}_\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^t\text{i}_\text{i}\left(\tau\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_\text{s}^{-1}\left[\frac{\displaystyle1}{\displaystyle\text{CLs}^2+\text{CRs}+1}\right]_{\left(t-\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau
\end{split}\tag2
\end{equation}